# StandardCharsets.UTF_8 on lower API lower than 19

Tags: java, android, http, encoding, url-parameters

I'm using this code to get scandinavian characters posted to php correctly.

Issue here is that StandardCharsets.UTF_8 is not supported before API 19

```
byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream());
wr.write( postData );
```

Field requires API level 19 (Current min is 14): java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets#UTF_8

How should I do this with API lower than 19?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use *forName* static method of *Charset* class:

```
byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

List of standard charsets you can find in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Comment: With Android SDK 31, Charset seems to reference StandardCharsets and cause a crash in API lower than 19. Bummer.

Comment: @faraday Did you find any solution for that? I mean a way to use UTF-8 on SDK 31, but also lower than 19?

Comment: @Joey I tried different ways of working around it but despite not directly referencing Charset, there seems to be indirect connections to it inside the SDK. I couldn't succeed yet.